# Echo Drop down selection

Tags: php

I have an edit section to edit a status and other various information.
I want the Status to be a drop down and then echo back. When using the code it just echos undefined. The text boxes (which I haven't included) work fine so I presume it is just because its a drop down instead of text boxes. The echo is in the first line of the code:

```
<?php echo $rrows['status']; ?>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='$("#edit<?php echo $rrows['id'];?
>").show("slow");'>Edit</a>


<div style="display:none;font: normal 11px arial; padding:10px; background: #e6f3f9" 
id="edit<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>">
Application Status: <select id="status<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>" name="status<?php 
echo $rrows['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $rrows['status']; ?>" >
<option value="<?php echo $rrows['status'];?>"></option>
<option value="Successful">Successful</option>
<option value="Not Successful">Not Successful</option>
<option value="Pending">Pending</option>
</select>
<input name="doSave" type="button" id="doSave" value="Save"

onclick='$.get("do.php",{ cmd: "edit", status:$("input#status<?php echo
$rrows['id']; ?>").val() ,user_level:$("input#user_level<?php echo $rrows['id']; ? 
>").val(),user_email:$("input#user_email<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>").val(),user_name: 
$("input#user_name<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>").val(),id: $("input#id<?php echo 
$rrows['id']; ?>").val() } ,function(data){ $("#msg<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?
>").html(data); });'>
 <a  onclick='$("#edit<?php echo $rrows['id'];?>").hide();'  
href="javascript:void(0);">close</a>

<div style="color:blue" id="msg<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>" name="msg<?
php echo $rrows['id']; ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Code like this is the reason why so many people don't like php, html and js.

Comment: @user1296762 Did you know you can use `<?=$variable;?>` instead, cutting 9 bytes per echo from your code

Comment: @LawrenceCherone http://www.hacksparrow.com/why-not-to-use-php-short-opening-tags.html

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `<?=` only works with short opening tags on.

Comment: +1 binarious, @LawrenceCherone that is horribly bad practice that is going to be deprecated shortly

Comment: @SetSailMedia wherever you read that its wrong! **deprecated shortly** prove it ;0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the name of that select box is 'status' followed by $rrows['id'], whereas you are simply referring to it as 'status'

Comment: So I've changed it to this: `Application Status: <select id="<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>" name="status"  value="<?php echo $rrows['status']; ?>" >`

Answer (score 0):

try: var_dump($rrows) instead of echo on the first line to see what is actually there. I use it often to debug.

Comment: array(40) { [0]=> string(2) "55" ["id"]=> string(2) "55" [1]=> string(9) "undefined" ["status"]=> string(9) "undefined" [2]